# Poor MongoDB read performance

Tags: java, performance, mongodb

I have a sharded collection containing flight information. The schema looks something like:

```js
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("537ef1bb5516dd401b5b109a"),
    "departureAirport" : "HAJ",
    "arrivalAirport" : "AYT",
    "departureDate" : NumberLong("1412553600000"),
    "operatingAirlineCode" : "DE",
    "operatingFlightNumber" : "1808",
    "flightClass" : "P",
    "fareType" : "EX",
    "availability" : "*"
}
```

Here are the statistics of my collection:

```js
{

    "sharded" : true,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "ns" : "flights.flight",
    "count" : 2809822,
    "numExtents" : 30,
    "size" : 674357280,
    "storageSize" : 921788416,
    "totalIndexSize" : 287746144,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 103499984,"departureAirport_1_arrivalAirport_1_departureDate_1_flightClass_1_availability_1_fareType_1" : 184246160
    },
    "avgObjSize" : 240,
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "nchunks" : 869,
    "shards" : {
        "shard0000" : {
            "ns" : "flights.flight",
            "count" : 1396165,
            "size" : 335079600,
            "avgObjSize" : 240,
            "storageSize" : 460894208,
            "numExtents" : 15,
            "nindexes" : 2,
            "lastExtentSize" : 124993536,
            "paddingFactor" : 1,
            "systemFlags" : 1,
            "userFlags" : 1,
            "totalIndexSize" : 144633440,
            "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 53094944,"departureAirport_1_arrivalAirport_1_departureDate_1_flightClass_1_availability_1_fareType_1" : 91538496
            },
            "ok" : 1
         },
        "shard0001" : {
            "ns" : "flights.flight",
            "count" : 1413657,
            "size" : 339277680,
            "avgObjSize" : 240,
            "storageSize" : 460894208,
            "numExtents" : 15,
            "nindexes" : 2,
            "lastExtentSize" : 124993536,
            "paddingFactor" : 1,
            "systemFlags" : 1,
            "userFlags" : 1,
            "totalIndexSize" : 143112704,
            "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 50405040,"departureAirport_1_arrivalAirport_1_departureDate_1_flightClass_1_availability_1_fareType_1" : 92707664
            },
            "ok" : 1
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I now run the queries from JAVA which look like:

```js
{
    "departureAirport" : "BSL",
    "arrivalAirport" : "SMF",
    "departureDate" : { 
        "$gte" : 1402617600000,
        "$lte" : 1403136000000
    },
    "flightClass" : "C",
    "$or" : [ 
        { "availability" : { "$gte" : "3"}},
        { "availability" : "*"}
    ] , 
    "fareType" : "OW"
}
```

The departureDate should be in between a range of a week and availability should be greater than the requested number or '*'.

My question is what can i do to increase my performance. When I query the database with 50 connections per host I only get about 1000 ops/s but I need to get something about 3000 - 5000 ops/s.

The cursor looks okay when I run the query in the shell:

"cursor" : "BtreeCursor departureAirport_1_arrivalAirport_1_departureDate_1_flightClass_1_availability_1_fareType_1"

If I forgot something please write me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would imagine taking out that $or would increase performance massively. Also what is your collection actually sharded on?

Comment: Okay I maybe can replace '*' at the insert to remove the $or.For test purpose it sharded on localhost. Two shards, one config server and one config DB.

Comment: What's the actual key you have sharded on? I.e. _id?

Comment: `db.runCommand({shardcollection:"flights.flight",key:{departureAirport:1,arrivalAirport:1,departureDate:1,flightClass:1,availability:1,fareType:1}})`

Comment: Ouch that uis one hell of a key and could be causing massive problem, it seems you should really be sharding on departureAirport really, then you are traversing only one shard for your query, maybe both depart and arrival airports

Answer (score 4):

The fact that a BtreeCursor is used doesn't make the query OK. The output of `explain` would help to identify the issue.

I guess a key problem is the order of your query params:

```
// equality, good
"departureAirport" : "BSL", 
// equality, good
"arrivalAirport" : "SMF",
// range, bad because index based range queries should be near the end
// of contiguous index-based equality checks
"departureDate" : { 
    "$gte" : 1402617600000,
    "$lte" : 1403136000000
},
// what is this, and how many possible values does it have? Seems to be
// a low selectivity index -> remove from index and move to end
"flightClass" : "C",
// costly $or, one op. is a range query, the other one equality...
// Simply set 'availability' to a magic number instead. That's
// ugly, but optimizations are ugly and it's unlikely we see planes with
// over e.g. 900,000 seats in the next couple of decades...
"$or" : [ 
    { "availability" : { "$gte" : "3"}},
    { "availability" : "*"}
] , 
// again, looks like low selectivity to me. Since it's already at the end, 
// that's ok. I'd try to remove it from the index, however.
"fareType" : "OW"
```

You might want to change your index to something like

```
"departureAirport_1_arrivalAirport_1_departureDate_1_availability_1"
```

and query in that exact same order. Append everything else behind, so scans must be made only on those documents that matched all the other criteria in the index.

I'm assuming that `flightClass` and `fareType` have low selectivity. If that is not true, this won't be the best solution.

Comment: You guessed right. Flightclass and fareType can only have three values. I'm going to try to implement your advices. Can you explain why you would remove them from index instead of moving them to the end of the index.

Comment: Good stuff though I agree despite being low selectivity they might still be good at the end of the index

Comment: Okay what should i try: `db.runCommand({shardcollection:"flights.flight",key:{departureAirport:1,arrivalAirport:1,departureDate:1,availability:1,flightClass:1,fareType:1}})` or `db.runCommand({shardcollection:"flights.flight",key:{departureAirport:1,arrivalAirport:1,departureDate:1,availability:1}})`

Comment: I also replaced '*'. Is it the better solution to put the range query of `departureDate` after `availability`

Comment: It depends on the distribution of values I'm afraid, so we're left to guess. I'd try the latter option and accept a presumed few hundred scans. The former won't really work because an eq after a range index doesn't really make sense. In MongoDB 2.6+, you could also try to put a separate index on `flightClass` and `fareType`, though I believe the index intersection feature doesn't yet work w/ compound ranges vs. compound equality, but I'm really not sure and it's worth a try.